# Can postgres return a deleted entry by index?

Tags: postgresql

Could it be that the database loaded from the dump contains invalid indexes by which the record is being searched for? The situation is such that if I delete one record, and then try to find it through the query `SELECT key, something_id FROM table WHERE something_id = 563 AND key = 'some_key' LIMIT 1;`, then postgres returns a value to me, but if I add primary key (id) to the select, then the record has not been found. The table has index on `key` and `something_id`

Comment: What do you mean by `:ID` field? You already have `something_id`. How was the dump/restore done? In other words from what Postgres version to what Postgres version and did you change OS and version of OS? Also see [Locale changes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes).

Comment: something_id is foreign key, so I added primary key of the record to the select query. Unfortunately, I cannot answer the rest of the questions, since other people were doing this about a few months ago

Comment: But OS and OS version didn't change

Comment: We where to know this how? Also you did not answer the other questions. Unless you do this and provide a complete example of what you are doing with sample input data and expected output vs actual output then there is not that can be done to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question.

```
SELECT id, key, something_id FROM table WHERE something_id = 563 AND key = 'some_key' LIMIT 1;
```

will return the rows you expect? And you records the value of ?

```
SELECT key, something_id FROM table WHERE something_id = 563 AND key = 'some_key' AND id=<val> LIMIT 1;
```

After you adding the condition : id=,  there is no result?
If so, could you do some vacuum analyze ?  This is somewhat strange.